# Match "ABC" from *ABC*, but not from **ABC**

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match `ABC` from `*ABC*`, but not from `**ABC**`.

I've this so far;

```
/[^\*]{1}\*([^\*]+)\*[^\*]+/
```

The strings to match can be any of the following.

`ABC **Don't match this** DEF`
`ABC *Match this* DEF`
`*Match this*`
`**Don't match this**`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). That is

```
(?<!\*)\*ABC\*(?!\*)
```

Which reads out as

> `*ABC*` not preceeded by `*`, and not succeeded by `*`.

Comment: Or if the flavor does not support lookbehinds (like JavaScript) adding this at the beginning might suffice as well: `(?!.*\*{2})`.

Comment: Or `\s\*ABC\*\s` if you can assure `*Match this*` will always be preceded and followed by a space.

Comment: @Felix - that lookahead will fail the regex if any `**` is in the string (`' *ABC* **'` will fail).

Comment: @sin: I know, that's why I said it *might* suffice ;) It clearly depends on the possible input.

Answer (score 1):

Your on the right track.
Without assertions: `/(?:^|[^*])\*[^*]+*(?:[^*]|$)/`
(use aioobe's regex with assertions, or any combination with/without).

Answer (score 0):

if the string starts and ends with "*" you could use this:

> /^*([^*]+)*$/