# Match "[abc]", "[[abc]", "[abc]]", but not "[[abc]]",

Tags: c#, .net, regex, escaping

I'm trying to match `[abc]` unless it's "escaped" by `[]` from both sides (so `[[abc]]` is considered as escaped, but not `[[abc]` or `[abc]]`).

Closest thing I could find is `(?<!\[)\[abc\](?!\])` from [Match "ABC" from *ABC*, but not from **ABC**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939405/match-abc-from-abc-but-not-from-abc), but it ignores match if it's escaped from only one side.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I noticed that you removed the `c#` tag from this question. The description of the `regex` tag says "all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool", so the `c#` tag that you removed was not insignificant and I therefore added it back along with `.net`, the regex engine that C# uses. My answer for example uses the support for variable-length lookbehind afforded by .NET.

Comment: **This is a duplicate of [Match pattern not preceded or followed by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907883/match-pattern-not-preceded-or-followed-by-string)**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that question is a bit more complex + this one has a `.net` specific solution which might not be suitable for that one

Comment: No regex here is .NET specific and will work in Java, Python, even JavaScript now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Thefourthbird's answer works, but would require that the main pattern `abc` be repeated, which goes against the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) that most are encouraged to follow.

In the interest of maximizing code reuse, one approach would be to use a capture group to capture `[abc]` and then use it in a negative lookbehind pattern to ensure that it is not both preceded by a `[` and followed by a `]`:

```
(\[abc])(?<!\[\1(?=]))
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5c%5babc%5d%29%28%3f%3c!%5c%5b%5c1%28%3f%3d%5d%29%29&i=%5babc%5d%0d%0a%5b%5babc%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5babc%5d+or+%5babc%5d%5d)

Note that this works for C# because .NET happens to support variable-length lookbehind patterns, which aren't supported by many other regex engines.

Answer (score 7):

The lookahead could be either at the left, or at the right to allow a single backet on the left or right, but not a double square bracket on the other side.

```
(?<!\[)\[abc]|\[abc](?!])
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%5b%29%5c%5babc%5d%7c%5c%5babc%5d%28%3f!%5d%29&i=%5babc%5d%0d%0a%5b%5babc%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5babc%5d+or+%5babc%5d%5d)

Comment: Hi, great quick solution (+1), but I thought you'd be interested in reading about a different approach of mine that helps avoid pattern duplication. Feedbacks from an experienced regex user like you would be greatly appreciated.